# Error $gte time error in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This mongo query returns a count > 0:

`db.COLLECTION.find (  { "timestamp" :{$gte: "2018-06-13 12:23:13.455535+00:00" }} ).count()`

But this query returns count returns 0:

`db.COLLECTION.find (  { "timestamp" :{$gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5).toISOString() }}  ).count()`

Answer (score 2):

When you `find` with a collection, you pass a list of object not an array.

So instead of this:

```
db.COLLECTION.find ( [ { "timestamp" :{$gte: "2018-06-13 12:23:13.455535+00:00" }} ]).count()
```

Do this:

```
db.COLLECTION.find ({ "timestamp" :{$gte: new Date("2018-06-13T12:23:13.455535+00:00") }}).count()
```

Note that the `[` is removed

Comment: But still same issue I am getting count value when I give numerical form time and not getting count exactly zero when given ( [ { "timestamp" :{$gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5).toISOString() }} ] ) like this I don't know what's wrong also even I tried with and without [ ] braces also same thing repeats

Comment: Remove the `.toISOString()` part in your query above

Comment: Thanks for that ,yes i tried  still the same issue and i cannot get where  i am doing wrong...count is 0 than also

Comment: I think you have wrong date string, try the edited answer, notice the `T` character in the date string

Comment: but their we are giveing in static format of time like this(2018-06-13T12:23:13.455535+00:00) which i have to change evry time which not possible for me but i want dynamic form like   new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5).toISOString() }}  ) ...i dont get the point before for diffferent query it worked dynamically but it is not working same query..

Comment: If you want compare with current date then just use `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

First argument to the find function should be an object not an array. You just need to remove [ ] simbols.